# Удаление элемента в стеке c++

Tags: c++

Есть код:

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 

struct Stack { 
  int info; 
  Stack *prev; 
}; 

Stack *push(Stack *top, int info); 
void view(Stack *top); 
void delLast(Stack *top); 

int main() { 
  int k, n; 
  Stack *top = NULL; 
  cout << "Enter the number of elements: " << endl; 
  cin>>n; 
  for (int i = 0; i<n;i++) { 
    cout << "Vvedite elem:\t" << endl;
    cin >> k; 
    top = push(top, k); 
  } 
  delLast(top);
  view(top); 
} 

Stack *push(Stack *top, int info) { 
  Stack *t = new Stack; 
  t->info = info; 
  t->prev = top; 
  return t;  
} 

void view(Stack *top) { 
  Stack *t = top; 
  if (t == NULL) { 
    cout <<  "Stack is empty!"; 
  } 
  while (t != NULL) { 
    cout << t->info <<" "; 
    t= t ->prev; 
  } 
} 

void delLast(Stack *top) {
  Stack *t = top;

  while (t != NULL) {
    if (t->prev == NULL) {
        delete t;
        return;
    }

    t = t-> prev;
  }
}
```

Моя **функция** `delLast` по задумке должна удалять последний элемент **стека**. **Функция** `view` выводит все элементы после удаления последнего. Вроде бы работает и в то же время вроде бы нет... Последний элемент становится равным **0**. Я так полагаю, что **функция** должна вывести только 2 элемента. Как исправить?

Comment: `delete t; cout << t->prev` - ничего не смущает?

Comment: @VTT, тут да, ошибочка, но всё равно окончательный стек элементов выводит функция `view`)

Comment: Вы должны найти предпоследний элемент. Соответственно

    while (t->prev != NULL)

Удаление таким образом происходит

    t->prev=NULL

Comment: @becouse, а разве `delete` не надо использовать, чтобы очистить память?

Comment: @ВладиславЖидко Нужно.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, так а когда тогда применять эту команду?)

Comment: Вы должны разделить 2 удаления. Из памяти и из стека.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  struct Stack {
  int info;
  Stack *prev;
};

Stack* push(Stack* &top, int info) {
  Stack *t = new Stack;
  t->info = info;
  t->prev = top;
  top = t;
  return top;
}
void view(Stack* &top) {
  Stack *t = top;
  if (t == NULL) {
     cout <<  "Stack is empty!";
  }
  for (Stack* i = top; i != NULL; i = i->prev) {
      std::cout << i->info << ' ';
  }
 }
void delLast(Stack* &top) {
    if (top != NULL) {
        int temp = top->info;
        Stack* Mystack = top;
        top = top->prev;
        delete Mystack;
        std::cout << temp << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: А теперь представьте, что стэк пустой, то есть `top` равен `nullptr`

Comment: Да вы правы не сделал проверку при удаление что стек не пустой

Comment: Используйте `nullptr`, а не NULL

Comment: Я знаю что с 11 стандарта лучше использовать nullptr но автор везде использовал NULL так что не стал использовать.